# sap connector 3.0 c# with sap hana

Tags: abap, hana, sap-dotnet-connector

Is it possible?

In another company always get info from RFC made at SAP R/3 and APP made in VS Studio C# (through sap connector).

```
Somebody told me to do the same, but in sap hana...
Can i build an RFC in SAP HANA ? and get the Information with the sap connector 3.0?
```

pd: What programing languages use sap hana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where should be the difference ? HANA Systems also have netweaver, abap capable and therefore You should have no problem to connect to a hana system. By the way, You can refer to those pics here to determine, WHICH type of hana-installation You have. There are three combinations, IIRC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a misleading. SAP HANA per se does not come with a NetWeaver/ABAP stack. There are other products like Suite on HANA or S/4 HANA that do that - but the SAP HANA platform as such doesn't come with a RFC receiver.

Comment: Thx for this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do all that,

SAP HANA has standard ODBC and also JDBC drivers that allow you to access the database directly with Java, .Net and others.

You can also take advantage of the odata services integrated into SAP HANA, especially in the .Net environment it makes a lot of sense.

The main SAP HANA db programming language is SQLScript, there is also a simple server side JavaScript api available.

Best Resource in regards to gain technical skills is to have a look at http://open.sap.com where you can find a lot of technical training sessions around SAP HANA.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply like to exchange data with a SAP HANA application, then ODATA would be the protocol of choice. This is quite different from RFC calls, but it's not too difficult to understand once you got behind RFC.

SAP HANA applications are done on a whole stack of different technologies. Data related processing is done in the DB layer with SAP HANA information models, SQL and SQL Script. Process orchestration and user facing interaction is done in the application layer, with JavaScript and the SAPUI5 UI library. It's this JS based application layer where you can define the ODATA services to provide access to the data and to data processing in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a RFC in SAP HANA since SAP HANA is an in-memory, column-oriented, relational database management system developed and marketed by SAP SE.

So you can't get information with SAP Connector 3.0 creating RFC in SAP HANA.

But you can create a RFC in SAP S/4HANA since SAP S/4HANA is SAP's ERP for large enterprises and is successor of SAP R/3 and SAP ERP and is optimized for SAP's in-memory database SAP HANA.

So you can get information with SAP Connector 3.0 creating RFC in SAP S/4HANA.

SAP HANA is written in C++ while SAP S/4HANA is written in ABAP.